# How can I use ToListAsync() method with ABP repository?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, iqueryable, abp

I've an application service method `GetWithName` and I want to write async version of this. To do this I've tried to use `ToListAsync()` but repository does not have this method.

```
public PagedResultDto<BookDto> GetWithName(SearchWithNameRequestDto input)
{
    var books = 
        Repository
        .Where(p => p.Name.Contains(input.Name))
        .ToList();

    return new PagedResultDto<BookDto>
    {
        TotalCount = books.Count,
        Items = ObjectMapper.Map<List<Book>, List<BookDto>>(books)
    };
}
```

How can I use async version of `ToList` method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ToListAsync` is ORM-dependent:

```cs
// using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

var query = Repository
    .Where(p => p.Name.Contains(input.Name));
var books = await query.ToListAsync();
```

For a DI (ORM-independent) solution, inject `IAsyncQueryableExecuter` and do:

```cs
// using Abp.Linq;

var query = Repository
    .Where(p => p.Name.Contains(input.Name));
var books = await _asyncQueryableExecuter.ToListAsync(query);
```